# i want to know in spring boot web app when we redirect from one jsp to another jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller

As you can see my hellow in request mapping is returning "welcome" jsp page but  if I want to use "a  href" in welcome jsp page to call view jsp page should I call the controller requestmapping ie "/products" or should I call viewtable jsp page directly?

welcome.jsp

```
< a href="??"</ahref>
```

viewtable.jsp

```
<h1>hellow<h1>
```

controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/hellow",method = RequestMethod.GET) public String
      abc(ModelMap model) { return "welcome"; }

@RequestMapping(value="/products", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllProducts(ModelMap model)
    {
        System.out.println("in controller");
        //return pls.productListAllRecords();
        List display;
         display=productservice.listAllRecords();
         System.out.println(display);
         model.addAttribute("records",display);
        // return "viewtable";
         return "viewtable";
    }
```

Comment: You should java script code in welcome.jsp, for example:
``` <script> window.location.href="/products"</script>```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to direct a user to the respective page, you could include a href property within an "< a >" tag with the requestMapping path included.

The following would direct to the above two paths when selected.

```
<a href="/hellow">Hellow</a>
<a href="/products">Products</a>
```

Comment: but how can i hit a normal html page or jsp page without getting through controller

Comment: The Controller must be used to retrieve the user request. If you would like a landing page, you can create a controller with the value "/" and you can return the String "home". Then in your WEB-INF folder with web pages, include a page called "home.html" which will map the empty ("/") request to the home.html page

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.GET) public String
      getHome() { return "home"; }

Comment: Thanks for the help it solved my query but still have one doubt hope u solve that ..... What i understood is in spring boot mvc everything should pass via controller there is no direct call between web pages am i right?

Comment: A controller is used to control the data flow of the web pages as per the user request. I would encourage you to look into the Spring layers (Controller, Service, Repository) for a better understanding of how a Spring application can handle requests end-to-end